# Named Credential Principal Data Disappeared

Tags: namedcredentials

I have a named Credential that has worked for months. I see in my logs that the integration successfully updated a record on 6 days ago, but today it failed due to a missing credential in Setup. I found that although the Principal still existed, both the parameters I had set had disappeared, and it was no longer accociated to the Permission Set I had it associated to. It also appears to have a different name, with some UUID appended that I'm pretty sure wasn't there before. The screenshot below is how I found it.

[image]

I added the Parameters again, and then I went into the Permission Set and added the credential there. I had to add it under the 'External Credential Principal Access' Section though, instead of the 'Named Credential Access' one (where I'm pretty confidient I had it set originally) and the credentials work fine again.

I don't see anything in the Audit Trail related to 'cred' in this time frame.

Any insight into that or other ideas of what would cause the Named Credential to be emptied out like this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the setup audit log for any changes to it?

Comment: Yes. I checked the audit log, but I just did so more carefully and added the one anomoly I found to the bottom of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like Pardot is your possible mystery intruder. Open a support case.

Comment: I gave bad information. I checked the integration logs better and found a more recent success that put the Pardot Audit Trail entry outside of the 'it broke' time frame. I did open a case though, at your (good) suggestion, @identigral

Comment: Update: Salesforce support does not have an explanation